# How to pass a variable / parameter (which includes slash) in the http post request in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am passing a variable or parameter in the the url during an http put request in angular and the variable that I am passing is in the (x/y) form. While passing such a kind of variable, the url that I am targeting is not getting hit due to the this variable form (x/y). I think because the url is changing while I am passing such variable. In short terms,

the URL that I want to send put request to
`http://localhost:5000/api/Transmission/{variable}/deleteDashboardAlert`

BUT the url this request is getting send to
`http://localhost:5000/api/Transmission/x/y/deleteDashboardAlert`

Following is the function that I am calling and passing arguments to ->

```js
deleteAlert(transmissionId, alertTypeId, description) {
 return this.http .put(
  `transmission/${transmissionId}/${alertTypeId}/${description}/deleteDashboardAlert`,
  {}
 );
}
```

So Basically in the above function, description variable is creating this problem

Comment: You want to access API end point which has dynamic value in it? i.e `../api/Transmission/123/deleteDashboardAlert`? correct?

Comment: Please post the code you're forming the URL with

Comment: @KamranKhatti Yes, that's right !

Comment:  hi , can you share you service code how do you pass the data and code related to send the data ?

Comment: @AG_24 I submitted solution, checkout my answer

Answer (score 2):

you can use `encodeURIComponent` to encode `variable` values

```js
deleteAlert(transmissionId, alertTypeId, description) {
 const variable = encodeURIComponent(`${transmissionId}/${alertTypeId}/${description}`);
 return this.http.put(`transmission/${variable}/deleteDashboardAlert`, {});
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur suggestion. encodeURIComponent method worked !

Comment: I 'm very happy to her that 

Answer (score -1):

You can add/append any dynamic value in your end point like below.

**demo.service.ts**

Edited: Added `encodeURIComponent` to encode passed parameter.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class DemoService {
    baseUrl = 'http://localhost:5000';
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

   getDemoData(someValue) {
     const endcodedValue = encodeURIComponent(someValue);
     const url = `${this.baseUrl}/api/Transmission/${endcodedValue}/deleteDashboardAlert`;
     return this.http.get(url);
   }

   getAnOtherDemoData(someValue1, someValue2 ) {
     const endcodedValue = encodeURIComponent(`${someValue1}/${someValue2}`);
     const url = `${this.baseUrl}/api/Transmission/${endcodedValue}/deleteDashboardAlert`;
     return this.http.get(url);
   }
 }
```

Comment: I dont believe this will solve the problem. The parameter or variable which we are passing and which contains slash needs to be send together.

Comment: I think encodeURIComponent will solve the problem but I don't test it 

Comment: @AG_24 I have updated my answer, hope this works for you.

Comment: @KamranKhatti what is the point of copy my answer 